# Amazon EMR Linux Instance User Account Access issues

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I created a user account on Amazon Linux Instance with root user. I found that if I create a user account(Example: ec2-user) that account will not have execute and write permissions on Hadoop Files System, Hive, Pig and other tools which are installed on Amazon EMR. If I have to give them explicit permissions I have to create a group which has permissions equivalent to superuser(root) account and add users to that group. Is there any other way I can set up access for those accounts to HDFS, Hive and Pigs etc.

Also while logging in as user the Linux command prompt is not prompting to enter any password even though I gave password for the user account while creating it. Is there anything configuration changes I need to make in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear to me.

But, let me attempt with whatever I suppose I understood.

Hadoop when security is enabled needs to have security for each user. It seems your user needs a separate space for writes and executions i.e. a Home directory.

First login as *'hdfs'* user in a terminal and then create a home directory for your user in HDFS. Please check if you have a directory called /user/{yourUser}. If, not create that. Then, make sure you make {yourUser} the owner of /user/{yourUser}.